# H-bridge using solid state relay instead bootstrap IC

Tags: h-bridge, solid-state-relay, bootstrap

experts! Good afternoon.

I am working on a project using a H-bridge. It must work at 100V and, then, i first designed a bootstrap circuit with 2 IR7304S (attached picture). Then i was wondering if two solid state relay could perform the same thing, replacing the bootstrap circuit and removing the MOSFETs. The objective is to let the current through the load to be bidirectional.

The switching frequency is quite slow (200Hz) and the load current is about +-70mA.

[image]

Comment: Before you design anything define DCR or ESR of load and thus surge current, inductance or device and supply impedance since you are also switching 1uF.

Comment: The photovoltaic array used in SSR is really slow, just for turn off/on like a switch.

Comment: Relay as in mechanical relay and 200 Hz? Even small signal relays operate in the ms range, so no.

Answer (score 1):

What your propose could work.  You could use a solid state relay if you can find one that has a turn-on/off time that is substantially less than 5ms.  Most SSRs are pretty slow.

Comment: Yes, the one I was looking for (LH1556AAC) has a turn-on/off time at maximum 3ms, which may fit. The biggest difference is the Rdon, which is 28Ohm for each solid state relay. The MOSFETS has very small values instead.

Comment: 28 /1kΩ is only 2.8% but ESR of 1uF cap is much lower.  So define all your loads accurately 1st (a priori) including relevant stray or cable reactance.

Comment: @TiagoC.M. 3ms may still be too long.  If the period of his waveform is 5ms (f=200Hz) then at 3ms turn on time the switch would spend all of its time in transition and none actually powering the load.  Substantially less than 5ms to me means something like 500us.

Answer (score 0):

Your drawing to the left does not make a lot of sense to me. The part you mention is a dual form A, so you could control two of them to make an H-bridge, if the switching and static (Rds(on)) characteristics are acceptable.

A note of caution- you must ensure the control is such that you get break before make every, **every** time the switches operate or you will get shoot-through and the SSR will be destroyed.

You can also use isolated gate drivers (photovoltaic or otherwise) and avoid the bootstrap circuit yet use N-channel MOSFETs. The half bridge drivers have the advantage of fairly fast operation and many of them take care of the necessary dead time (see above) for you. You can also provide the high side supply for the half-bridge driver chips externally (say with a DC-DC converter) and not use the bootstrap feature, which has advantages in some applications.